# Problemas con instalación de XAMPP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

Desde hace unos días he tenido inconvenientes con una instalación de XAMPP, que utilizaba para la creación de un sitio WordPress.

El problema radica en un cambio del sistema operativo de mi ordenador, anteriormente tenía Windows 10, pero por problemas de rendimiento decidí volver a Windows 7, con una instalación limpia desde cero. Mis conocimientos en informática no son tan avanzados, así que he pensado que con copiar todos los archivos de XAMPP de mi sistema con Windows 10 y pasarlos al Windows 7 (instalando la misma versión de XAMPP que tenía en Windows 10) no pasaría nada y podría continuar utilizándolo de la misma forma en que lo había estado utilizando

Sin embargo, hoy me he dado cuenta que no es así. A pesar de tener todos los archivos de XAMPP y utilizar la misma versión, al intentar acceder a WordPress me saltan cientos de errores. Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiese orientarme en esto, al menos para no perder la página que ya tenía hecha con WordPress.

Saludos

Comment: Podrías por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir algunos de los errores? Posiblemente copiaste más de la cuenta...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes copiar es la carpeta htdocs con todo su contenido que es alli donde se alojan tus proyectos locales en la pc. Esta carpeta se encuentra dentro de la carpeta xampp. Y luego en tu nuevo sistema operativo instalar la misma version xampp que tenias anteriormente y reemplazar la carpeta htdocs que alli se encuentra.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado, pero en pantalla solo me aparece "Error al establecer una conexión con la base de datos"

Comment: porque tenes que exportar la base de datos y guardarla. Luego desde phpmyadmin creas una base de datos con el mismo nombre y importas la base que guardaste.